# logits and labels must be same size logits_size

Tags: tensorflow, convolution, tensorflow-estimator

hi i used my own dataset for train the model but i have error that i mention below . my dataset has 124 class and lables are 0 to 123 , size is 60*60 gray , batch is 10 and result is :

lables.eval() --> [ 1 101 101 103 103 103 103 100 102 1] -- len(lables.eval())= 10

orginal pic size -- > (?, 60, 60, 1)

First convolutional layer (?, 30, 30, 32)

Second convolutional layer. (?, 15, 15, 64)

flatten. (?, 14400)

dense .1 (?, 2048)

dense .2 (?, 124)

error

```
ensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: logits and 
labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [40,124] and 
labels shape [10]
```

code

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
   # Reference to the tensor named "image" in the input-function.
   x = features["image"]
   # The convolutional layers expect 4-rank tensors
    # but x is a 2-rank tensor, so reshape it.
    net = tf.reshape(x, [-1, img_size, img_size, num_channels])
    # First convolutional layer.
    net = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=net, name='layer_conv1',
                           filters=32, kernel_size=3,
                            padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
    net = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=net, pool_size=2, strides=2)

    # Second convolutional layer.
    net = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=net, name='layer_conv2',
                   filters=64, kernel_size=3,
                   padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
    net = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=net, pool_size=2, strides=2)

    # Flatten to a 2-rank tensor.
    net = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(net)
    # Eventually this should be replaced with:
    # net = tf.layers.flatten(net)
    # First fully-connected / dense layer.
    # This uses the ReLU activation function.
    net = tf.layers.dense(inputs=net, name='layer_fc1',
                  units=2048, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    # Second fully-connected / dense layer.
    # This is the last layer so it does not use an activation function.
    net = tf.layers.dense(inputs=net, name='layer_fc_2',
                  units=num_classes)

    # Logits output of the neural network.
    logits = net
    y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits=logits)
    y_pred_cls = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
         spec = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                  predictions=y_pred_cls)
    else:
         cross_entropy = 
               tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels,
                                                              logits=logits)
          loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
          optimizer = 
          tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=params["learning_rate"])

          train_op = optimizer.minimize(
               loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
           metrics = \
                  {
                   "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, y_pred_cls)
                   }

           spec = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
                         mode=mode,
                         loss=loss,
                         train_op=train_op,
                         eval_metric_ops=metrics)

     return spec`
```

this lables comes from here via tfrecords:

```
def input_fn(filenames, train, batch_size=10, buffer_size=2048):
# Args:
# filenames:   Filenames for the TFRecords files.
# train:       Boolean whether training (True) or testing (False).
# batch_size:  Return batches of this size.
# buffer_size: Read buffers of this size. The random shuffling
#              is done on the buffer, so it must be big enough.

# Create a TensorFlow Dataset-object which has functionality
# for reading and shuffling data from TFRecords files.
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=filenames)

# Parse the serialized data in the TFRecords files.
# This returns TensorFlow tensors for the image and labels.
dataset = dataset.map(parse)

if train:
    # If training then read a buffer of the given size and
    # randomly shuffle it.
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=buffer_size)

    # Allow infinite reading of the data.
    num_repeat = None
else:
    # If testing then don't shuffle the data.

    # Only go through the data once.
    num_repeat = 1

# Repeat the dataset the given number of times.
dataset = dataset.repeat(num_repeat)

# Get a batch of data with the given size.
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

# Create an iterator for the dataset and the above modifications.
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

# Get the next batch of images and labels.
images_batch, labels_batch = iterator.get_next()

# The input-function must return a dict wrapping the images.

x = {'image': images_batch}
y = labels_batch
print(x, ' - ', y.get_shape())
return x, y
```

i generate labeles via this code for example image name=math-1 , lable = 1

```
def get_lable_and_image(path):
lbl = []
img = []
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.png')):
    img.append(filename)
    lable = filename[41:].split()[0].split('-')[1]
    lbl.append(int(lable))

lables = np.array(lbl)
images = np.array(img)
# print(images[1], lables[1])

return images, lables
```

i push images and lables to create tfrecords

```
def convert(image_paths, labels, out_path):
# Args:
# image_paths   List of file-paths for the images.
# labels        Class-labels for the images.
# out_path      File-path for the TFRecords output file.

print("Converting: " + out_path)

# Number of images. Used when printing the progress.
num_images = len(image_paths)

# Open a TFRecordWriter for the output-file.
with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(out_path) as writer:

    # Iterate over all the image-paths and class-labels.
    for i, (path, label) in enumerate(zip(image_paths, labels)):
        # Print the percentage-progress.
        print_progress(count=i, total=num_images-1)

        # Load the image-file using matplotlib's imread function.
        img = imread(path)

        # Convert the image to raw bytes.
        img_bytes = img.tostring()

        # Create a dict with the data we want to save in the
        # TFRecords file. You can add more relevant data here.
        data = \
            {
                'image': wrap_bytes(img_bytes),
                'label': wrap_int64(label)
            }

        # Wrap the data as TensorFlow Features.
        feature = tf.train.Features(feature=data)

        # Wrap again as a TensorFlow Example.
        example = tf.train.Example(features=feature)

        # Serialize the data.
        serialized = example.SerializeToString()

        # Write the serialized data to the TFRecords file.
        writer.write(serialized)
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the code you posted. logits have the expected shape. I suspect you do something fishy with the labels. Can you post the part where you generate the labels?

Comment: i edited and i hope its helpful to find a solution . also i printed content of lables tensor lables.eval() --> [ 1 101 101 103 103 103 103 100 102 1] -- len(lables.eval())= 10 thanks

Comment: The issue might come from the reshape, which can flatten the batch of images in the wrong way. Try to print the tensor shape at every step in your model to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: thanks for comment , flatten. (?, 14400) is printed from flatten method and you can find others above .

Comment: the document says "labels: Tensor of shape [d_0, d_1, ..., d_{r-1}] (where r is rank of labels and result) and dtype int32 or int64. Each entry in labels must be an index in [0, num_classes). Other values will raise an exception when this op is run on CPU, and return NaN for corresponding loss and gradient rows on GPU" . my lables is 1 to 124 should i change lables to 0 to 123 or the cpu makes error ?

Comment: What is the shape of the layer `net = tf.layers.dense(inputs=net, name='layer_fc_2',
                  units=num_classes)` output? Do you get something like `[batch_size,2]` when you run a batch through the graph?

Comment: dense .2 (?, 124) is output of layer_fc_2

Comment: my lable isn't sparse format .